# What is the differences and possible similarities of closures and currying?

Tags: closures, currying

I've read through some of the post on here about closures and currying but I feel like I didn't find the answer.  So what's the differences and possibly the similarities of closures and currying?  Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Currying* is really a mathematical concept first and foremost.  It's the just observation that for any *n*-ary function *f: S<sub>0</sub>×...S<sub>n</sub> → R*, you can define a new function *fprime* (just found a markdown bug!)  with *n-1* parameters where that first parameter is replaced by a constant.  So, if you have a function `add(a,b)`, you can define a new function `add1(b)` as

`add1(b) ::= add(1, b)`

...reading "::=" as "is defined to be."

A *closure* is more of a programming concept.  (Of course, everything in programming is a mathematical concept as well, but closures became interesting because of programming.)  When you construct a closure, you bind one or more variables; you're creating a chunk of code that has some variables tied to it.

The relationship is that you can use a closure in order to implement currying: you could build your `add1` function above by making a closure in which that first parameter is bound to 1.

Comment: What you have described is partial evaluation rather than currying. Related, but not exactly the same.